# How to compare two columns in excel (with little different criteria)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Hi i have two columns(list of username and list of girl names) like below

[image]

Username    girlname    Expected output
John Dennies    Lina    boy
Barak Obama     Savita  boy
Lina Josef  Lynn    girl
Amanda wolve    vaneesa girl
Jerry J. Walt   amanda  boy
Linac M take        boy

Girlname contains list of 5000+ names. Now i want column 1 (username ) to be compared against the girlname and whenever there is a match it should display a "match" in another column where i will put the condition. 
Problem is as girlname is just a substring of the column one .its very difficult for a novice like me to generate the formula. I have formula which works for exact match but this query is little different than the usual ones hope i get an answer here.

Comment: what is the format of your girlname column? i.e. is it always "first name" "last name" ? I don't understand what "Lina Savita Lynn Vanessa" is, is that 2 first names followed by 2 last names, or two separate names by "surname"/"forename" or viceversa?

Comment: NO its not always first name and last name it can be something like Firstname . Initial of dad . surname . or first name dad name surname. It can be anything.

Comment: well if it always starts with firstname, and that's all you need to pull to work with, then it's enough,  you can use `MID`

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed put that as an answer because it is better than my array type formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$6& " ",A2))*1)>0,"Girl","Boy")
```

It will search the girls name column to see if any match any but the last name.  If so it will return `Girl` if not `Boy`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. that was quick . However i want the match to be in front of column A and not against girlnames. Example here Lina josef should be identified as girl name so there shall be word like match or girlname against her name.

Comment: @rohan please update your original post with expect output.

Comment: @rohan please see the edit.  I have done the reverse.

Comment: Hi scott i uploaded the image which includes the expected output.

Comment: @rohan see edit, you may need to refresh the screen to see it.

Comment: Thank you very much scott for your efforts . i been searching for this since yesterday.You are the champ :)

Comment: I wish i could vote one up but this is my first question so its not allowing .

Comment: @rohan you can select it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It does not matter the number of Reps you have.  As the one posing the question you can mark it as correct.

Comment: While everything is good but I m getting a minor problem . for example. If i include a girl name as "ansu" .. According to above formula name Himanshu Desai is a girl . basically Himanshu is boy name which happens to contain a girl sub-string which is anshu (is there any way i can avoid that?) thanks

Comment: Also if i simply include girl name without surname or anything it detect it as a boy. i believe thats because of space that is added. is there any way to deal with it. ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I can't see your image because of our webfilter at work:

However, what you want is this:

`=MID(girlname,1,FIND(" ",girlname))`

this returns you the first forename, which you can then use to compare against your username

then use `=COUNTIF(username,midvalue&"*")` where midvalue is the forename you extracted with the mid function above..

You could write this as a single function as such:

`=IF(COUNTIF(username,MID(girlname,1,FIND(" ",girlname))&"*"),"Match","No Match")`

Comment: I would use left but you would get his desired outcome by using MATCH and an IF statement: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),B:B,0)),"Girl","Boy")`

Comment: Or you can use countif like you have.